# Dictionaryをファイルに書きだした後、値を書き換えるとクラッシュする

Tags: ios, swift

Dictionary を writeToFile で書きだした後、値を書き換えると EXC_BAD_ACCESS が発生してクラッシュします。
次のコードは XCode の SingleViewApplication テンプレートにボタンを追加してIBActionを設定したものですが、ボタンを2回押すと `dictionary["key"] = "value"` のところでアプリがクラッシュします。

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

    var dictionary : [String:String] = [:]
    var path: String = NSHomeDirectory()! + "/Documents/dictionary"

    @IBAction func buttonAction() {
        dictionary["key"] = "value"
        (dictionary as NSDictionary).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
    }
}
```

writeToFile の行をコメントアウトするとクラッシュしないので、ファイル書き出しに関係があるかもしれませんが、いくつか奇妙な点があります。

まず、今のところ iPhone6 でしか発生していません。
確認できた範囲では次のようになりました。

- iOS8.1.3(iPhone6) : クラッシュする
- iOS7.1.2(iPhone5) : 正常
- iOS8.1(iPhone5 Simulator) : 正常

次に buttonAction() をこのように書き換えるとクラッシュしなくなります。

```
    @IBAction func buttonAction() {
        dictionary["key"] = "value"
        (dictionary as NSDictionary).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
        dictionary["key"] = "value"
    }
```

writeToFile の直後に`dictionary["key"] = "value"` を足しただけですが、なぜかクラッシュしなくなります。

やりたいことはアプリのConfig情報ををファイルに保存したいだけなのですが、何か解決方法や別の方法などありませんでしょうか？

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> (dictionary as NSDictionary).writeToFile(path, atomically: true)

これを以下に書きかえてみてください。

```
let objcDictionary = NSDictionary(dictionary: dictionary)
objcDictionary.writeToFile(path, atomically: true)
```

いいたいのは、SwiftのDictionaryを、いったんObjective-CのNSDictionaryにコピー（変換？）してからファイル書き出ししてみては？ということです。

Comment: ありがとうございます。確かにコピーすれば元のオブジェクトに影響なさそうですね。実際に試してみましたが動作も問題なさそうでした。